# ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\PostsController does not exist Lumen 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am new to Lumen, and I got error when using Postman: `ReflectionException Class App\Http\Controllers\PostsController does not exist`

Here is my `PostsController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controller;

use App\Post;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller{
/*content*/
}
```

I already checked location of my controller. I also read the same problem and tried the solutions, but it was not work for me. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks before

Comment: you have `Controllers` in your namespace `App\Http\Controllers\PostsController` and in your file you have `Controller` check it `namespace App\Http\Controller`

Comment: @ravisachaniya I got it, I missed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller's namespace is wrong, Check the namespace. Good luck

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong namespace in your controller file.

You need to change it to `Controllers`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```